# how to use data after fetch it in js ? i get the data but idk why i cant use it

Tags: javascript, json

i have a small problem that i can't use the data after fetch it from local json file
this is screenshots :
here the data in the console:

[image: 1]

here is my code:

```
fetch('api_link.json')
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
    console.log('data:', data);
  })

export const project_info = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PROJECT_INFO_REQUEST });

    var { data } = await axios.get('HERE I WANT TO PUT THE DATA FROM THE JSON FILE');

    dispatch({
      type: PROJECT_INFO_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
```

another screenshot
to more explain:
[image]

can anyone helo me please

#note
i am python backend developer :)

this is first time i use react js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function arguments are scoped to that function, and aren't accessible outside of that function.

What's more: There's no guarantee that the network request will have resolved by the time you call `project_info`.

Save the promise returned from `fetch` in a variable, then that promise will be in scope for `project_info`.

```
const api_data = fetch('api_link.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())

export const project_info = () => async (dispatch) => {
            try {
                dispatch({
                    type: PROJECT_INFO_REQUEST
                });

                const url = await api_data;

                var {
                    data
                } = await axios.get(url);

                dispatch({
                    type: PROJECT_INFO_SUCCESS,
                    payload: data,
                });
```

Note that `axios` and `fetch` are two APIs for doing the same job. It doesn't really make sense to mix them.